# Python: Nested Loops not running as Expected

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I have a loop that writes a command to a modem, and reads the modem until it finds 'OK' or 'ERROR'. The loops works; once. For some reason, as soon as the loop finishes for the first time, it breaks. Here's the code:

```
for modem in ser:
    for port in modem:
        print port.name
        port.write('ati\r\n')
        a=port.read(size=2000)
        a=a.splitlines()
        t=False
        while t!=True:
            for line in a:
                print line
                if line=='OK' or line=='ERROR' or '$GP' in line:
                    t=True

  print 'howdy ho diddly doo'
```

I've also made the while loop inside like this:

```
while True:
    for line in a:
        print line
        if line=='OK' or line=='ERROR' or '$GP' in line:
            t=True
        if t==True:
            break
```

However, with both versions, it results as such:

```
COM71
ati

Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
Model: MC8705
Revision: T3_5_2_1AP R517 CNSZXD00000128 2012/02/07 13:03:25
IMEI: 353567040568900
IMEI SV: 5
FSN: CC30942172510
3GPP Release 7
+GCAP: +CGSM,+FCLASS,+DS


OK
howdy ho diddly doo
>>> len(Ports) #Ports is ser (the list that I pass through for the function)
4
>>>
```

I know with certainty that the length of the ser is greater than one, and that the loop should be running more than once. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not obvious that ser has a few modems. Try iterate over ser and output modem reprs and iterate over every modem and output port names. If there is really a few items in ser then we have something to discuss.

Comment: What is the thinking behing the nested `while`+`for`-loop? Unless I am mistaken, the while loop will either run infinitely, looping `a` again and again, or only once. The `if` condition is either true or false in each iteration; `a` does never change inside this loop!

Comment: @peroksid I edited it to include the output as well as after I query the length of the list.

Comment: Positive it's right in the source file, it's just copying and pasting it into the editor.

Comment: You should add a `print len(modem)` right under `for modem in ser`, to make sure your second for loop has something to iterate over.

Comment: a is not supposed to change in the for loop. It's reinitialized when it moves on to the next port, which it doesn't.
The for loop inside the while loop is to go through a, and check for 'OK' or 'ERROR', which is when I know the modem has properly responded.

Comment: Strange indeed. I think he wants to take reading from port inside while-loop.

Comment: I don't see how your second code snippet would ever end; that `break` is for the `for` loop, while in the first snippet, the sentinel variable is for the `while` loop.  They're doing different things...

Comment: Another indentation error. It belongs to the while loop in the source.

Comment: Oh I understand what I've done. I misunderstood your first suggestion @tobias_k. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: It's that I don't initialize a in the while loop like I should be doing, and that the break was on the wrong indentation level.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why the outermost `while` loop runs only once although you have more than one modem. Is this still a problem, or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: This was a problem that was cause by something unrelated earlier in the module. I just confused myself when I missed the earlier error, and then made stupid mistakes with logic flow trying to fix it.

Comment: @BraydonKains Okay, that clears things up. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your inner `while` loop:

```
a=port.read(size=2000)
a=a.splitlines()
t=False
while t!=True:
    for line in a:
        print line
        if line=='OK' or line=='ERROR' or '$GP' in line:
            t=True
```

You iterate the lines of `a`, and set the `t` flag that will end the loop to `True` if one of the lines is "OK", "ERROR", or the like. However, the `for` loop goes over *the same* set of lines `a` in each iteration of the `while` loop! So either the `while` loop stops after the first iteration, if the first set of lines satisfies the conditions, or you run into an infinite loop.

Probably you are missing another `a=port.read(size=2000)` inside the `while` loop.